# Problem with SFTP on Arch-ARM

Tags: raspberry-pi, sftp, arch-arm

I have installed Arch ARM on a Raspberry Pi 3 and created a new user.
Pretty much everything is working; I have copied my public/private keys and can ssh into Arch on the Raspberry Pi.

NOTE I am only attempting to connect on my local network.

However I cannot seem to FTP into the server.
I am using the latest Filezilla on macOS, and Arch ARM is up to date.
I am using SFTP in Filezilla with similar settings I use to connect with Raspbian on a Pi.

The following is the message log on a connection attempt

```
Status:         Connecting to archpi.local...
Status:         Connected to archpi.local
Error:          Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
Error:          Could not connect to server
Status:         Waiting to retry...
Status:         Connecting to archpi.local...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    open "XXX@archpi.local" 22
Command:    Pass: *******
Status:         Connected to archpi.local
Error:          Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

Comment: @jasonwryan I know you have corrected my tag before, BUT when I enter arch as a tag THIS IS NOT ONE OF THE OPTIONS!

Comment: Yes, oddly you have to add the hyphen before the autocomplete will add [tag:arch-arm] as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After MUCH searching I found a solution to change `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` into `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and this appears to have solved the problem.

There is NO `usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` in Arch!